# Domain Driven Design modelling queries

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm building a new application and am new to Domain Driven Design. I've been reading through the documentation and I've managed to model most of the domain model but I would like some advice about two queries:

1. I have two domain objects channel and program. I've modelled these both as entities as both can be accessed independantly. A channel can have a list of programs so I have put this as an attribute of channel. My query is how should I populate the program list. Is it OK for the getChannerById method in ChannelService to first get the channel information and then call the ProgramService to get the list of programs for the channels e.g:

   ```
   Channel {
     String channelId
     List <Program> programList
   }

   Program {
     String programId {
   }

   ChannelService {
      Channel getChannelById(String channelId)
   }

   ProgramService {  
      Program getProgramById(String programId)
      List <Program> getProgramsByChannelById(String channelId)  
   }
   ```
2. I have a product domain object but some of its attributes (e.g. specification and compatability) involve quite time consuming operations. These attributes are not required all the time so is it OK to put these as part of the domain object and have seperate service methods that populate these attributes when required e.g.

   ```
   Product {
       String productId
       Specification specification
       List <Product> compatibleProducts
   }

   ProductService {
       Product getProduct(String productId);
       void getProductSpecifications(Product product);
       void getCompatibleProducts(Product product);
   }
   ```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When designing entities in DDD you shouldn't create associations from one entity to another such that the association is used for display or query purposes alone. While it is true that a channel has a set of programs, is the association between channel and the set of its programs required for the channel entity? More importantly, if you're only considering the query aspect then you may not need be forcing DDD upon your code. Instead, when designing entities consider the behavior that these entities need to implement. If your entities have no behavior but are only used as data containers then you don't need DDD. To answer your question, I would use read model classes that satisfy requirements of each query. For example, for your product model, if one query requires the specification attribute and another doesn't, create distinct read-model classes for those queries. These classes are not entities, they are simple read-only value objects, they don't have any behavior and their job is to represent data. In regards to implementing the query you have several options. Calling both the ChannelService and the ProgramService is one option. However, if the data is all stored together in a single database, why not just create a repository that returns all required data with one call? Take a look at my [post](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) on read-models in DDD for more on this topic.